# applicationinsights-react-native - jest failing

Tags: javascript, react-native, ts-jest

● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

D:\develop\project\node_modules\@microsoft\applicationinsights-react-native\dist-esm\index.js:5
import { ReactNativePlugin } from "./ReactNativePlugin";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

   6 | } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
   7 |
>  8 | import {ReactNativePlugin} from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-native';
     | ^
```

We are working on fixing this issue,let me know if you see this error in different environments.

Please find the below Error Screenshot

Comment: Question seems like its for an internal project and wasnt really meant to be posted on a public forum